# Reference a subfunction with arrow notation in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, arrow-functions

I have a function in Angular/Typescript where I'm subscribing to an Observable and then, in that subscription, using the Observable data to do certain things within a subfunction with arrow notation. Finally, I want to return the result of all of this, but I would need to first return the variable inside the function with arrow notation and then return that "arrow notated function" in the main function. I don't know how to do this though. I need the arrow notation so I can access certain variables of the class with `this`, so I don't think I can remove the arrow notation.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.permittedList = this.getUsersList();
}

getUsersList() {
    this.authService.user$.subscribe(
      async (user) => {
        this.user = user;
        //Doing things with this.user to get `permitted`
        return permitted;
      })
    //return arrow function?
}
```

Comment: You cannot synchronously return a value that doesn't exist yet. How is getUsersList being used? Can you return an observable and let the code that calls getUserList subscribe to it?

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to do, could you elaborate your question better and specify all the variables and functions used?

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks, this is true. I call getUsersList in ngOnInit and set the returned result to variable (added this info in the question too). So, would a solution be to let getUsersList return an Observable and subscribe to it in ngOnInit?